# Why isn't my dwarf's strange mood being satisfied?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

My clothier dwarf has gone into a strange mood and has taken over my clothier's shop. He is demanding the following:

- bars... metal
- cloth... thread
- blocks... brick

Well, I'm pretty sure I've provided all that, but the dwarf still isn't budging.

[image]

In this picture you can see my strange mood dwarf in the clothier shop, a row of plant fiber cloth beneath him, some stone blocks to the right of that, some metal bars above, and some yarn cloth to the right.

So why isnt the dwarf grabbing the materials and starting on his mysterious craft?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the wrong type of cloth. There are three types of cloth, and the dwarf will only accept the kind he wants. You have plant fiber and yarn cloth, but he wants silk cloth.

Comment: Ohh... I thought any type would do.

Comment: Yeah, this is something that took me quite a while to figure out.